# Linux cgroupsv2 missing PSI files

Tags: raspbian, cgroups

I am currently trying to read the Memory and IO Pressure from the cgroup filesystem.
I can confirm that I am indeed running cgroupsv2 as the output from
`cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers` gives me

```
cpuset cpu io memory pids
```

Within the `/sys/fs/cgroup` folder I have the following files/folders

```
cgroup.controllers  cgroup.procs        cgroup.threads         cpu.stat     user.slice
cgroup.max.depth    cgroup.stat     cpuset.cpus.effective  init.scope  memory.stat
cgroup.max.descendants  cgroup.subtree_control  cpuset.mems.effective  io.stat     system.slice
```

However I was also expecting there to be the corresponding pressure files for each of the controllers

```
cpu.pressure io.pressure memory.pressure
```

The system is running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)` with `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1` in `/boot/cmdline.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the kernel was not compiled with the PSI feature.
To check if you kernel has this feature then first check the kernel config.
using `sudo modprobe configs; zcat /proc/config.gz > .config` and `grep "CONFIG_PSI" .config` to check if its set or not.
If the `CONFIG_PSI`is disabled then it can be enabled by passing `psi=1` on the kernel command line during boot.
However if the grep returns with `#CONFIG_PSI is not set` then you need to recompile the kernel to enable PSI.